# Jetpack Infinite Scroll won't fire

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-jetpack, infinite-scroll

I have carefully followed the instructions at [OttoPress](http://ottopress.com/2012/jetpack-and-the-infinite-scroll/), and read all the documentation at [Jetpack.me](http://jetpack.me/). I feel like I understand what should work, but for some reason Infinite Scroll is not firing.

I have installed Jetpack onto my Wordpress installation and disabled all features apart from Infinite Scroll.

[image]

I created a `content.php`, as per the recommendations at OttoPress, and my page (`page-news.php`) loads that content just fine, and as I'd expect. The code looks like this:

```
<div id="masonry">
  <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 
    get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );                                      
  endwhile; ?>
</div>
```

With that all working correctly, I then added the following to `functions.php`:

```
function bones_infinite_loop_init(){
  add_theme_support( 'infinite-scroll', array(
    'footer'         => false,
    'type'           => 'scroll',
    'footer_widgets' => false,
    'container'      => 'masonry',
    'wrapper'        => false,
    'posts_per_page' => false
  ));
}
add_action( 'init', 'bones_infinite_loop_init' );
```

When that didn't work, I even tried adding:

```
'render'         => 'bones_infinite_scroll_render',
```

And created a function with the post formatting in it.

I've also tried:

```
'type'           => 'click'
```

But nothing appears on the page, no extra posts are loaded when I scroll to the end of the page, and `infinite-scroll` does not appear as a class on the `body` element.

The are also no errors in the developer console. There are no errors when I set `WP_DEBUG` to true. I've also tried disabling all other plugins.

What am I missing?

I'm wondering if it's to do with any of the following:

1. I'm trying infinitely scroll Custom Posts
2. On `page-news.php` I have `'posts_per_page' => 3` and maybe that's conflicting somehow?
3. I've missed a crucial (but obvious) step in setting things up

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Are you using some sort of Javascript Masonry? And if you just use the default instructions for Jetpack, it still doesn't work? http://jetpack.me/support/infinite-scroll/

Comment: @RachieVee Yes, I'm using MasonryJS. And yes, I've followed the documentation at jackpack.me

Comment: I had an issue getting Jetpack to work with Masonry - have you tried disabling masonry just to see if Jetpack works?

Comment: @RachieVee Thanks, just tried that. No change. I'm sure I've missed something really obvious.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you want it to do what happens on [Jetpacks' example](http://twentytwelvedemo.wordpress.com/blog/) without a button, just scroll down and more posts appear until there's no more?

Not sure if this will help, but your code has the wrapper parameter set to false while Jetpack's example where they have the [footer parameter section](http://jetpack.me/support/infinite-scroll/) has it set to true:

```
add_theme_support( 'infinite-scroll', array(
    'type'           => 'scroll',
    'footer_widgets' => false,
    'container'      => 'content',
    'wrapper'        => true, //This is true whereas your example is false
    'render'         => false,
    'posts_per_page' => false,
) );
```

You can also try running the add_theme_support function outside of the action hook you're using and seeing if anything happens.

Also, I would try disabling Jetpack and in page-news.php, confirm that there is default pagination going on. If not, then [troubleshoot the pagination](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pagination#Troubleshooting_Broken_Pagination) if it's non-existent because it's possible that it's messing with Jetpack. Infinite scroll needs WordPress' default pagination to exist I believe because it breaks each section of posts by their "pages".

I'd say if there are no console errors in your browser, or PHP errors when you set your [wp-config's debug to true](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress#Example_wp-config.php_for_Debugging) - then you may have to seek more advanced help or maybe even provide a link to the site for deeper investigation. Good luck!

Comment: I set the debug to true, but still no errors. I tried setting wrapper to true, and no change. I'll look into the pagination. Thanks.